# Build fails because there is a main function

Tags: c#, program-entry-point

I'm currently working on a service, but it fails to build the solution. I have this code of the main function:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ServiceBase.Run(new Service1());
}
```

When I comment the whole thing the build succeeds. I also commented out STAThread and serviceBase... alone, but it still failed so the problem is the `static void Main`. I need it to run my service though so I can't leave it out.

The output type is set to *Windows Application* right now. When I change that to *Class Library* the build succeeds, but that creates .dll files and my application need to be an .exe file.

Why is it failing?

This is the output from Build:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Myst Service, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Users\Username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Myst Service\Myst Service\Service1.cs(23,21,23,25): error CS0017: Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I searched the entire solution for Main and it appears there is a static void Main in Program.cs too. Is that common?

Comment: When a build fails you get a error message, you need to include the error message in your question as a edit.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Where can I find the error message? I get no pop-up, in the bottom left* corner it says build failed that's how I know it failed...

Comment: Go to `View` up in the menu bar and you should see a `Error List` option for a window you can open. http://i.stack.imgur.com/yL2qc.png

Comment: @ScottChamberlain There are no errors there, as I said when I comment that piece of code it does work and theres no error in that code as you can see so yea...
I'm going to try putting it in a fresh project, this one is fresh too but we'll see

Comment: Then open the `Output` window instead, clear it before you build then build it with a error. Copy the entire text of the output window as a edit to your question at the botton

Comment: You should be building this as a console app. That is what the Main entry point is for.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Done
@ Kevin It doesn't work on console app either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your error output log it states

> error CS0017: Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.

This means there is more than one `Main` in your program. Either get rid of the second one or go in to the project properties and set the entry point you want under the `Startup object` area.

[image]

P.S.: For a Windows service you need the output type to be `Console Application`.

Comment: Okay that works, thank you! Installing the service worked too but I get an error when I want to start the service, that has nothing to do with this question though